# Arduino Due 16U2 Programming Port Documentation

Tags: arduino-due

Are there any documentation or whatsoever on what the 16U2 does when trying to program the Sam3X in Arduino Due?

I reallynwant to know what's wrong with my made up board but can't get pass the No Device Found problem.

Been searching it but I can't find any. I can't understand the hex file burned on the MCU.

Comment: did you upload the firmware to the ATmega 16u2? the firmware is in arduino/hardware/sam/1.6.11/firmwares/atmega16u2

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/Upgrading16U2Due

Comment: Yes, I'd already uploaded that firmware to the 16U2.

Answer (score 0):

The 16u2 is merely acting as a usb to UART adapter. You can just as well use an ft232 or other serial adapter.

Of course the 16u2 needs firmware installing on it in order to function. That firmware is available (possibly bundled with the ide, or for download, not sure at the moment).

Comment: But I believe it is also responsible in asserting the reseta and erase pins that is needed for the SAMBA bootloader in the Sam3x and something about the CDC.

Comment: And you should have copied that from the due schematic, yes? And the firmware you install in the 16u2 does all that it needs to.

Comment: Yes. I've got everything (connections, voltage levels) of the pins in my board and due the same during power up but I'm still getting the No device found error. So I'm think that something I'd miss and I want to see it by looking at the code and what to expect on the pins using a scope.

Comment: If you're going to that sort of level then you really need a physical Due to compare it with.